# Can't see function output while using gdb, (Error accessing memory address.. Input/output error)

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I'm seeing a problem in using gdb (actually I'm using ddd which is a grahpic debugger using gdb inside) which is that I cannot see a function's return value.
With a simple program, I could see that I can print a function's output. For example, if an object.peek() return an integer, if I type `p object.peek()`, then I get for example `1234`. And I remember printing any values when I'm degging a C or C++ program.
I'm now running and analyzing a complex program which is a python program containing a shared object library written in C++. I can set a breakpoint in C++ code and follow steps. But when I try to see some functions' output like `param.input_dim_size()`, the debugger give me the output :

```
(gdb) p param.input_dim_size()
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 0.
Error accessing memory address 0x232460: Input/output error.

An error occurred while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(caffe::NetParameter::input_dim_size() const) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
```

Has is something to do with attaching two debuggers to the same program? or using C++ library inside Python? (I guess not). Or is there any restriction for seeing the output of functions in gdb?

Comment: I suspect the function is dependent on some other parts of the application having run, and you're trying to call it before that setup has been done, so it's getting an error.

Comment: That's clearly not C! And not related to Python either - unless you omitted relevant information.

Comment: Can you put a break point on the method? Or list it out? Maybe it is not fully setup

Comment: Hmm, looks like it has to with inline functions. most functions I tried to run are defined as inline functions.. But at the same time, when I print a variable via a pointer, it gives me error too..